# How can I programmatically determine if an "touchUpInside" event occured?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

It seems like if this method will be called any time the user touches my view:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == self && [touch tapCount] >= 1) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

I've implemented this in an UIScrollView. The documentation for UIEvent doesn't mention those touchUpInside, touchUpOutside, etc. events that are available in Interface Builder when making connections to action methods.

Actually I want a method to be called only upon one of those "touchUpInside" events, rather than on any kind of touch.

Comment: You could break down and see if the touchLocation of the UITouch object falls within the view of the same UITouch object.

Answer (score 3):

You want `touchesEnded:withEvent:`. The `touchesBegan` method gets called when a touch or series of touches starts within a UIResponder; the `touchesEnded` method gets called when that batch of touches is done (i.e. your user stops touching the screen/lifts a finger).

Comment: This is helpful, but unfortunately, it doesn't entirely answer the question. How can you determine in touchesEnded:withEvent: whether a touchUpInside event occurred?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way is to create an IBAction and hook it up to the touchUpInside event in InterfaceBuilder.app.

Everything time a touchUpInside happens, your IBAction will be called.

If you are creating programmatically, outside of IB, you can still hook up the IBAction.

Comment: I create 20 images in a grid, which extends dynamically as the user scrolls. How would I hook those up to an IBAction? IB would have to know in which view that happens, right? How could I tell IB that "generically"?

Comment: Check out the UIControl class ref and  addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Comment: You only need one touchUpInside method.  And IB doesn't need to do the connecting -- you can as images are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I link up an IBAction to a textfield:

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(your method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [UIControlEventTouchUpInside](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents/uicontroleventtouchupinside?language=objc).

> A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.

AFAICS, you need to implement [`touchesEnded:withEvent:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621084-touchesended?language=objc).

```swift
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let point = touches.first?.location(in: self), self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
            //didTouchUpInside
        }
    }
```

> If you override this method without calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, even if your implementations do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Vadoff's technique is neat, however don't forget to cleaned up the touch event by calling super function. Here is the complete code.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    BOOL touchedUpInside = NO;
    if (self.isTouchUpInside) {
        touchedUpInside = YES;
    }

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];    

    if (touchedUpInside) {
        // touched up inside
    } 
}
```